# What is the new endpoint for

Tags: rest, azure-cognitive-services, evaluate

I am using the evaluate REST API from the Academic Knowledge API from Microsoft Cognitive service using the REST endpoint:

https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?

In the suscription page at Microsoft Cognitive Service it says:

> Important Notice: starting on 1/17, our API endpoints will be changing. 
>   If your API is currently using "api.projectoxford.ai" endpoint, you will need to switch to the new API endpoint (see our API reference for that) or you may experience latency. The old API endpoints will be deprecated 90 days following this change.

I'm trying to find the new REST endpoint and how to use it but I could not figure out. Could you please point me to the documentation?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For most users, the endpoints for Microsoft Cognitive Services are moving to `https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`.  The rest of the path is unchanged.